# image processing

Tags: mobile-robot, computer-vision, algorithm, beagle-bone, first-robotics

I am making a Robot goalie, the robot is supposed to detect whether a ball has been thrown in its direction , sense the direction of the ball and then stop it from entering the goal post. A webcam will be mounted on top of the goal post. The robot is required to only move horizontally (left or right), it shouldn't move forwards or backwards. The robot will have wheels, the image processing will be performed by raspberry pi which will then send the required information to a micro controller which will be responsible for moving the robot in the required direction(using servo motors). Which image processing algorithm will be the best to implement this scenario?

Comment: Will the ball and posts and field be standard and uniform colors?

Answer (score 5):

Ball detection using vision is not extremely difficult, especially if the ball is easy to recognize. There are a lot of tutorials and blogs which give a detailed explanation on how to implement an algorithm to solve this problem:

- [Raspberry Pi Ball tracking](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Ball-tracking/)
- [Using OpenCV on the Beagleboard to track an Aibo pink ball](http://mechomaniac.com/OpenCVBallTracking)
- [OpenCV Tutorial C++ - Color Detection & Object Tracking](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com.es/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html)
- [Ball Tracking / Detection using OpenCV](http://anikettatipamula.blogspot.com.es/2012/12/ball-tracking-detection-using-opencv.html)
- [Ball detection with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770948/ball-detection-with-opencv)
- [Design of an Image Processing Algorithm For Ball Detection](http://archive2.cra.org/Activities/craw_archive/dmp/awards/2010/Emole/FinalPaper_Emole.pdf)
- [Fast Object Tracking – Robot Computer Vision](http://www.lirtex.com/robotics/fast-object-tracking-robot-computer-vision)
- ...